# Dividing Long Equation using Split

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I have a long equation as below,

[image]

As the equation is too long, I am working to split it. Unfortunately it was not successful. Confused where could be the mistake. Could you assist to point it.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:1b}
\begin{split}
Index & = \sum_{\forall a,b \in set, a \neq b}{\left[ \\
  & 5*k_{X}\left(i_{a,b}\right)*\mathds{I}_{\left[i_{a,b} \in E_{X}\right]} + \\
  & 3*k_{Y}\left(i_{a,b}\right)*\mathds{I}_{\left[i_{a,b} \in E_{Y}\right]} + \\
  & 2*k_{Z}\left(i_{a,b}\right)*\mathds{I}_{\left[i_{a,b} \in E_{Z}\right]}\right]}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Update1:

Thanks to all for your help. I tried all and the below works like a charm.

```
\begin{equation} \label{eq:1c} 
\begin{split} 
Index = \sum_{\forall a,b \in set, a \neq b}
&\Bigg[ 5*k_{X}\left(i_{a,b}\right)*\mathds{I}_{\left[i_{a,b} \in E_{X}\right]} + \\ 
&\mbox{ }\hspace{0.35in} 3*k_{Y}\left(i_{a,b}\right)*\mathds{I}_{\left[i_{a,b} \in E_{Y}\right]} + \\ 
&\mbox{ }\hspace{1in} 2*k_{Z}\left(i_{a,b}\right)*\mathds{I}_{\left[i_{a,b} \in E_{Z}\right]}\Bigg] 
\end{split} 
\end{equation}
```

Update2:

Thanks Bernard and Egreg. I learnt many news ways to succinctly write an equation. Sorry if I had abused \left and \right. I am bookmarking this page for future reference. I do not have enough reputation to Vote Up the answers. Will revert back to this soonest once I have enough reputation.

As I am using 2 columns per page and if `i(a,b)` has to fulfill additional conditions such that for example,

```
[i_{a,b} \in E_{Z}\ \&\ i_{a,b} \notin E_{Y}\ \&\ i_{a,b} \notin E_{X}]
```

Hope it is ok to divide those line if too long.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:1b}
\begin{split}
\mathit{Index} = \smash[b]{\sum_{\substack{a,b \in \mathit{set}\\a\neq b}}}
\;\bigl[
  & 5k_{X}(i_{a,b})\mathds{I}_{[i_{a,b} \in E_{X}]} +{} \\
  & 3k_{Y}(i_{a,b})\mathds{I}_{[i_{a,b} \in E_{Y}\ \&\ i_{a,b} \notin E_{X}]} +{} \\
  & 2k_{Z}(i_{a,b})\mathds{I}_{[i_{a,b} \in E_{Z}\ \&\ i_{a,b} \notin E_{Y}\ \&\ i_{a,b} \notin E_{X}]}
\bigr]
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're abusing `\left` and `\right`, to begin with. None of their occurrences in your code is needed, actually.

Here's my proposal, using `\substack` for avoiding a too long subscript to the summation and “smashing” its bottom. I omitted `\forall` that's usually implied in the notation and also `*`, that is not frequently used in mathematics to denote multiplication (it usually has other meanings, for instance the convolution product).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:1b}
\begin{split}
\mathit{Index} = \smash[b]{\sum_{\substack{a,b \in \mathit{set}\\a\neq b}}}
\;\bigl[
  & 5k_{X}(i_{a,b})\mathds{I}_{[i_{a,b} \in E_{X}]} +{} \\
  & 3k_{Y}(i_{a,b})\mathds{I}_{[i_{a,b} \in E_{Y}]} +{} \\
  & 2k_{Z}(i_{a,b})\mathds{I}_{[i_{a,b} \in E_{Z}]}
\bigr]
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Note also `\mathit` that's recommended for multiletter variable names.

[image]

Comment: Question ... Why place the `+` signs at the ends of lines?  (I'm more used to these operators being placed at the beginning of the next line, as shown on pages 118-119 of the [AMS Style Guide](https://www.ams.org/publications/authors/AMS-StyleGuide-online.pdf).

Comment: @barbarabeeton I’ve got no strong position on this; in this particular case, the symbols in the next line would make for awkward alignment.

Answer (score 3):

I would cut the equations in one of these two ways — two  lines is enough. I changed the summation index to what I think it is really, and used the `\mathclap` and `\MoveEqLeft` commands from `mathtools` to prevent too much horizontal spacing around the equal sign. Also, writing ‘Index’ in math mode makes this word look as the succession of 5 variables, not as a word; use `mathrm` (or `\mathit` if you wish) instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:1b}
\begin{aligned}
\MoveEqLeft[8]\mathrm{Index}   =  \sum_{\mathclap{\{( a,b) \in \mathrm{set},\;  a \neq b\}}}\left[
  5*k_{X}\left(i_{a,b}\right)*\mathds{I}_{\left[i_{a,b} \in E_{X}\right]}\right.  +\\[-2ex]
 &    3*k_{Y}\left(i_{a,b}\right)*\mathds{I}_{\left[i_{a,b} \in E_{Y}\right]} +
  \left. 2*k_{Z}\left(i_{a,b}\right)*\mathds{I}_{\left[i_{a,b} \in E_{Z}\right]}\right]
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\vskip 1cm
\begin{equation} \label{eq:1b}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
\mathrm{Index}    & =  \sum_{\mathclap{\{( a,b) \in \mathrm{set},\;  a \neq b\}}}\left[
  5*k_{X}\left(i_{a,b}\right)*\mathds{I}_{\left[i_{a,b} \in E_{X}\right]}\right.   &  &
    + 3*k_{Y}\left(i_{a,b}\right)*\mathds{I}_{\left[i_{a,b} \in E_{Y}\right]}\\[-2ex]
   &  &  & +\left. 2*k_{Z}\left(i_{a,b}\right)*\mathds{I}_{\left[i_{a,b} \in E_{Z}\right]}\right]
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You must have `\left[` and `\right]` in the same line or you separate by `\right.` in the first line and `\left.` in the last line.

```
\begin{equation} \label{eq:1b} 
\begin{split} 
Index & = \sum_{\forall a,b \in set, a \neq b}\left[ \right.\\ 
      & 5*k_{X}\left(i_{a,b}\right)*\mathds{I}_{\left[i_{a,b} \in E_{X}\right]} + \\ 
      & 3*k_{Y}\left(i_{a,b}\right)*\mathds{I}_{\left[i_{a,b} \in E_{Y}\right]} + \\ 
      & \left.2*k_{Z}\left(i_{a,b}\right)*\mathds{I}_{\left[i_{a,b} \in E_{Z}\right]}
        \right] 
\end{split} 
\end{equation}
```

Comment: It's better to size delimiters that span multiple lines manually using `\big`, `\Big` etc. Using `\left.` and `\right.` can result in inconsistent sizes.

Comment: For another way in the same idea of @Ian Thompson

     \begin{equation} \label{eq:1b}
     \begin{split}
     Index = \sum_{\forall a,b \in set, a \neq b}&\Bigg[ 5*k_{X}\left(i_{a,b}\right)*\mathds{I}_{\left[i_{a,b} \in E_{X}\right]} + \\
     &\mbox{ }\hspace{0.35in}  3*k_{Y}\left(i_{a,b}\right)*\mathds{I}_{\left[i_{a,b} \in E_{Y}\right]} + \\
     &\mbox{ }\hspace{1in}   2*k_{Z}\left(i_{a,b}\right)*\mathds{I}_{\left[i_{a,b} \in E_{Z}\right]}\Bigg]
     \end{split}
     \end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

Use instead `align`

```
\begin{align*} 
Index  = &\sum_{\forall a,b \in set, a \neq b} \left[ 
  5*k_{X}\left(i_{a,b}\right)*{I}_{\left[i_{a,b} \in E_{X}\right]} +  \right. \\
 &  \left. + 3*k_{Y}\left(i_{a,b}\right) * {I}_{\left[i_{a,b} \in E_{Y}\right]} + 
   2*k_{Z}\left(i_{a,b}\right)* {I}_{\left[i_{a,b} \in E_{Z}\right]}\right]
\end{align*}
```

Comment: I think, if use align numbered of equation not in middle way.

Comment: @somkiat_t definitely!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the enviroment

```
\begin{multline}
........
\end{multline}
```